# Ошибка в форме отправки

Tags: php, javascript, html5, opencart

Есть сайт - [ТЫК](http://xn--80adiogdyt6a.com.ua/index.php?route=zapchasti/zap)

Делаю на нем отправку формы, на почту приходит все письмо полностью, как сделать чтобы из selecta отправлялось на почту только выбранный пункт
[image: ТЫК]

Comment: Приложите код формы

Comment: Вот -
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B621Dy8PNC4dUU5DN3RKaFdQOVU?usp=sharing

Comment: Приложи код к вопросу, не на стороннем источнике. Ссылка к тому-же не рабочая.